# ModuleNotFoundError in Python AzureFunction App for custom package

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I developing a `Python` `Azure Function` app and I use a `Custom Package` for this project. because of the custom package I build and install all dependencies in my `CI/CD` pipeline before making `zip` file and deploying it on `Azure` based on this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=python%2Cyaml&pivots=v2). my problem is when the app deployed successfully, I got an error about the `Custom Package` is not found when I run the app. The full error message is

> Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '{custom package name}'. Cannot find module. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module.

I check this [documentation](https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound) and double check my artifact. the only thing I found based was on documentation the package name format must be '`<package-name>-<version>-dist-info`' but in my artifact is '`<package-name>-<version>.dist-info`'.

Also, I try these configurations in `Azure Function` but it does not make a difference.

Configurations:

- BUILD_FLAGS=UseExpressBuild
- PYTHON_ISOLATE_WORKER_DEPENDENCIES=0
- SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true
- ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`ModuleNotFoundError`** generally occurs when the required Python package is not correctly installed into the directory "**`.python_packages/lib/site-packages`**". This directory should be archived together with the files of the Python function app to be a ZIP that will be deploy to Azure Function App.

For your case, since the Python package is your custom package, it is recommended to publish the custom package into an Artifacts feed in your Azure DevOps project for use:

1. [Create a private Artifacts feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/project-scoped-feeds?view=azure-devops) in your Azure DevOps project if you do not have one. And ensure you have added **PyPI** as the upstream in the feed.

   [image]
2. Build and publish your custom Python package into the feed. [You can set up a pipeline to do this for your package.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pypi?bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
3. In the pipeline to deploy your Python function app, before the task which runs the "**`pip install`**" command, add the [Python pip authenticate task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/pip-authenticate-v1?view=azure-pipelines) like as below.

   ```yaml
   steps:
   . . .

   - task: PipAuthenticate@1
     displayName: 'Pip Authenticate'
     inputs:
       artifactFeeds: {Your Artifacts feed name}

   . . .
   ```
4. Ensure you have listed the custom package into the **`requirements.txt`** file of your Python function app. And in the code of your Python function app, ensure you have set to correctly **`import`** the custom package.
5. When running the following "**`pip install`**" command in the root directory of your Python function app, it will install your custom package from the Artifacts feed and the public packages from the **PyPI** upstream into the directory "**`.python_packages/lib/site-packages`**".

   ```bash
   pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
   ```
6. Then you can use the [Archive files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/archive-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines) to archive the directory "**`.python_packages/lib/site-packages`**" together with the files of your Python function app to be a ZIP.

---

Answer (score 0):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '{custom package name}'. Cannot find module.

*ModuleNotFoundError* occurs when your package is not listed in the **`requirements.txt`** of your Function App, If you want to install your package separately, You will have to add **`apt-get package-name`** command or **`pip install package-name`** command in the **startup command** section of **Azure Function DevOps task seperately.**

***Startup command in yaml:-***

```yaml
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'xxxxxx (xxxxxx)'
              appType: 'functionAppLinux'
              appName: 'siliconfuncv2'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              startUpCommand: 'apt-get update apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 libunwind-dev gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio'
```

There are **`two ways you can install Custom packages in your Linux Function app.`**

Refer my [**SO answer1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77749362/install-linux-dependency-during-the-python-webapp-zip-deployment-azure-oryx/77925172#77925172) where **I have added the Custom packages in the Source code Folder and then added the Folder name as path in the **`requirements.txt`** while Deployment of the Web App the packages inside the Folder are added automatically.** You can use same concept to Deploy custom package to your Function App.

Refer [**SO answer2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77679608/how-to-use-a-private-python-github-package-in-an-azure-function-app/77701924#77701924) ***where you can upload your custom packages in Github and then use this **`git+https://$GITHUB_TOKEN@github.com/sid24desai/pycode.git@main`** url with your Github PAT token/githuborg/repository/ in your requirements.txt like below:-***

This is my **`requirements.txt:-`**

```
azure-functions
git+https://ghp_xxxxxxx3OD@github.com/sid24desai/pycode.git@main
```

***My Azure Devops yaml pipeline:-***

```yaml
trigger:
- master

variables:
 
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxxx97cb2a7'

  
  functionAppName: 'siliconfunc65'

  
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.6'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.10 

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'xxxxx subscription (xxxxxxxb2a7)'
              appType: 'functionAppLinux'
              appName: '$(functionAppName)'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

[image]

**Additional Reference:-**

[Azure Function Deployment using CI-CD pipeline Differing from VsCode Deployment - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76704037/azure-function-deployment-using-ci-cd-pipeline-differing-from-vscode-deployment/76704620#76704620) My SO answer